# Implement Slideshow of videos and images

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, slideshow, android-videoview

I want to implement slideshow of videos and images. When app is opened it should start with slideshow of images and in between some videos to play, when a video is playing, the slideshow should stops sliding and when video has finished the slideshow starts sliding again.Are there any ways to do it? I am new to android, please help me out

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful library that lets you do this - https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-slideshow-widget

You can also see a working demo of this library - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marvinlabs.widget.slideshow.demo

If you want to implement the logic yourself, you can make the use of a timer and change the image references in the image view.

Comment: can u post the code for both image and video slider @Vinay Gaba

Comment: I dont see videos in demo app also.it's showing only images

Comment: It would be exactly what I am looking for but, the demo application is no longer in the store, I did some quick tests to compile the project but without success, something similar but more recent?